Is there anyone who knows how to reset the BIOS of a Dell Latitude 7420 to factory settings?
At the company where I previously worked, they gave me a Dell Latitude 7420 laptop. The BIOS is locked, and I can't format the computer. It's a shame to have it sitting there unused, and I can't find a way to format it to put it to good use.
The company told me that they don't have any information to provide regarding the BIOS password, and I don't know what to do. I already tried unplugging the main battery and leaving it disconnected for an entire day. It doesn't have a CMOS battery either to "drain the BIOS."
Is there anyone who knows how to reset the BIOS to factory settings?

Bios passwords can typically be generated from the serial number (for dell anyway). Google bios password generator?

Only the machine owner can remove or change the supervisor's password. Most modern laptops cannot be forcefully reset.

Some older Dell BIOS passwords can be found at https://bios-pw.org/ I got the one for a freecycled Latitude D830 there.

@OrganicMarble On the pwgen-for-bios github page there is the issue Dell laptop latitude 7420 #254 from May 2024. This suggests bios-pw.org doesn't currently have the code for a Latitude 7420

The DELL How to Reset or Clear the BIOS Password article gives two options:

To follow the Deleting or changing an existing system setup password section of the service manual for the computer. The Clearing BIOS (System Setup) and System passwords section of Latitude 7420/Latitude 7420 2-in-1 Service Manual says:

To clear the computer or BIOS passwords, contact Dell technical support as described at Contact Support. For more information, go to Dell Support Site.


How to recover a forgotten BIOS password on a Dell laptop contains:

BIOS passwords cannot be recovered. If you have forgotten one of the passwords that is set in the BIOS, contact Dell Technical Support to obtain a password release code. The password release code is based on the unique password prompt that is generated using information from your Dell laptop.
NOTE: Dell technical support requires ownership information about the Dell computer to prevent unauthorized users from obtaining the password release code.



I'm not sure what information Dell technical support require to verify the ownership information.

Any proof of purchase will do but the OP likely won't be able to get that from the company and at the end of the day the company is still the owner and they're the ones who must contact Dell support for this issue. Finally, after ownership has been confirmed, they'll tell them the motherboard must be replaced for the usual fee.
